# How to delete a row in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, row

I already have add/delete rows dynamically in Javascript, there is no problem in adding rows, only having a problem with deleting rows.
For now, what I have made is when I want to delete a row **it always deletes the last one**, so I think **`I want if it only can be deleted the selected row`**, and I don't know how to modify the script to what I wanted be.

Here is the script:

```
var i=0;
function addRow()
{
 i++;
  m.r.value = i;
  var tbl = document.getElementById('table');
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
  var iteration = lastRow - 1;
  var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

  var cellLeft = row.insertCell(0);
  var textNode = document.createTextNode(iteration);
  cellLeft.appendChild(textNode);

  var cellRightSel1 = row.insertCell(1);
  var sel = document.createElement('select');
  sel.name = 'name' + iteration;
  sel.setAttribute("onchange", "choosec(this);");    
  var item = new Option("","");
  sel.options[sel.length] = item;
    <?
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){                                    
    ?>
  var item = new Option("<?=$data["Name"];?>","<?=$data["ID"];?>");
  sel.options[sel.length] = item;
  <? } ?>
  cellRightSel1.appendChild(sel);

  var cellRightSel2 = row.insertCell(2);
  var sel = document.createElement('select');
  sel.name = 'class' + iteration;
  sel.setAttribute("onchange", "choosepoint(this);");    
  var item = new Option ("","");
  sel.options[sel.length] = item;
    <?
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result_sub)){                                    
    ?>
  var item = new Option("<?=$data["Class"];?>","<?=$data["ID"];?>");
  sel.options[sel.length] = item;
  <? } ?>
  cellRightSel2.appendChild(sel);

  var cellRight = row.insertCell(3);
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.id = 'point' + iteration;
  cellRight.appendChild(div);
}


function removeRow(){
  var tbl = document.getElementById('table');
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
  var rem = lastRow - 1;
  if (lastRow > 2) tbl.deleteRow(rem);
}
```

Help is appreciated, thanks.

**My solved problems:**

```
function removeRow(t){
      var i = t.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
      var tbl = document.getElementById('table');
      var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
      var iteration = lastRow - 1;
      tbl.deleteRow(i);
    }
```

Comment: A global var named `i`? Inline event handler? Have you considered using jQuery? (Actually, before people like Raynos complain about suggesting jQuery, you can also improve that without jQuery - but why write more code than encessary)

Answer (score 3):

try it like this

```
<tr onclick="removeRow(this);">...</tr>
```

then in javascript method

```
function removeRow(row){
  var tbl = row.parentNode;
  var index = row.parentNode.rowIndex;
  if (index > 2) tbl.deleteRow(index);
}
```

**I found one good example suitable your requirement. [check here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/03/dynamically-add-remove-rows-in-html-table-using-javascript.html)**

Comment: Thanks Mr.rajkumar, I have figured out the problems :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that needs to be changed:

```
  var rem = lastRow - 1;
```

Right now, that's always going to be the last row. You can build some logic around that to pass in an index, or hunt for a string, or whatever, but tbl.deleteRow() needs to delete at a particular index.

If you wanted to delete the 3rd row, for example:

```
var rem = 2; //zero-based index
```